# Python Tkinter. How to store entry via button in label

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I really need help with some code. I don't expect you to write it for me, since it is a school project, but I am just really lost and need help.

The code I am writing is some sort of production system.
It doesn't need to actually be able to send a task anywhere, since this is just an imagined scenario.

The code has to consist of three files: data.py, model.py and gui.py.

- Gui can access the two other files
- Data can only access model
- Model can't access either of the other two.

My teacher had written some of the code witch I have continued on. Some of the text is in danish, but most comments are in English.
The code is as follows.

**data.py**

```
from model import *

class Data(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.units = []
    self.finished_tasks = []

def __str__(self):
    result = "These tasks have been finished: "
    for i in self.finished_tasks:
        result += str(i)
    return result

def task_done(self, unit):
    done_task = unit.task_done()
    if done_task != None:
        #TODO: add to list of finished tasks
        pass

def add_task(self, name, amount, unit):
    s = Springroll_task(name, amount)
    unit.add_to_queue(s)

def read_from_database(self):#doesn't actually read from db..
    self.units.append(Production_unit("maskine1"))
    self.units.append(Production_unit("maskine2"))

    self.add_task("Miniruller", 100, self.units[0])
    self.add_task("Maxiruller", 200, self.units[0])
    self.add_task("HowIRoll", 3000, self.units[0])
    self.add_task("RulleMarie", 40, self.units[1])
    self.add_task("Rullesten", 500, self.units[1])
    self.add_task("Toiletpapirsruller", 6000, self.units[1])
```

**model.py**

```
    class Springroll_task(object):

    def __init__(self, name, amount):
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + str(self.amount)


class Production_unit(object):

    def __init__(self, amount={}, name={},):
        #name of the production unit
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
        #the current task
        self.current_task = None
        #the tasks in the queue
        self.springroll_queue = []
        #the size of the queue
        self.queue_size = 0

    def __str__(self):
        #TODO
        return self.name + " " + str(self.amount)

    def add_to_queue(self, task={}):
        if self.current_task == None:
            self.current_task = task
        else:
            self.springroll_queue.append(task)
            self.queue_size += 1
            #remember to update queue_size
            pass

    def task_done(self):
        #TODO: remember the old current task.
        #Set the current task to be the first in the queue (and remove from queue)
        # - if there is a task in the queue.
        #return the old current task.
        #remember to update queue_size
        self.queue_size -= 1
        pass
```

**gui.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from model import *
from data import Data

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, unit):
        self.mod = Production_unit()
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)  
        self.grid()
        self.unit = unit
        self.create_widgets()



    def create_widgets(self):
        self.unit_name_lbl = Label(self, text = self.unit.name)
        self.unit_name_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        self.cur_prod_lbl = Label(self, text = "produktion nu: ")
        self.cur_prod_lbl.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        self.prod_lbl = Label(self, text = "produkt")
        self.prod_lbl.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.amount_lbl = Label(self, text = "antal")
        self.amount_lbl.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)
        #Label for production now
        self.amount1_lbl = Label(self, text = "             ", bg ="red")
        self.amount1_lbl.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.amount2_lbl = Label(self, text = "      ", bg ="red")
        self.amount2_lbl.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)
        #Button for task finished
        self.finished_but = Button(self, text = "Opgave afsluttet", bg ="pink", command=self.mod.task_done)
        self.finished_but.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = W)

        #Label for queue
        self.queue_lbl = Label(self, text = "Kø")
        self.queue_lbl.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)
        #Label for production queue
        for i in range(0,3):
            self.name_lbl =Label(self, text = self.mod.springroll_queue, bg="red", width= 6)
            self.name_lbl.grid(row = 5+i, sticky = W)

        for j in range(0,3):
            self.qt_lbl =Label(self, text = self.mod.springroll_queue, bg="red", width= 4)
            self.qt_lbl.grid(row = 5+j, column = 1)

        self.new_lbl = Label(self, text = "Ny")
        self.new_lbl.grid(row = 10, column = 0, sticky = W)
        #Entry for entries
        self.eq1_ent = Entry(self, text = "", width=6)
        self.entry_name = self.eq1_ent.get()
        self.eq1_ent.grid(row = 11, sticky = W)

        self.ea1_ent = Entry(self, text = "", width=4)
        self.ea1_ent.grid(row = 11, column = 1, sticky = W)
        #Button for add to queue
        self.add_but = Button(self, text = "Tilføj til kø", bg ="pink", command=self.mod.add_to_queue(self.ea1_ent.get()))
        self.add_but.grid(row = 11, column = 2, sticky = W)





    def done(self):
        d.task_done(self.unit)
        self.redraw()

    def add(self):
        n = "Nyt navn" #read from gui
        a = "Nyt antal" #read from gui
        d.add_task(n, a, unit)
        self.redraw()


    def redraw(self):
        #TODO
        pass

# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Daloon")
root.geometry("300x300")

d = Data()

d.read_from_database()

p = d.units[0]

app = Application(root, p)

root.mainloop()
```

So it currently looks like this:

What I need to be able to do is to take an input in the bottom two entry widgets and put them in one of the 4 label widgets above, beginning from the top and then in the queue afterwards, this should happen when I press the button add_but, which seems to be gone currently.
After that I need the task stored in the data file when the "Opgave afsluttet" button is pressed.

I really hope someone is able to help me!

I edited it with some suggestions, and am calling the right self.eq1_ent.get() now, I think. I dont get any error any longer, now I just don't really know how to make it do what I want.
Edit 2: I am slowly getting some stuff, so i have made changes in the model.py and gui.py...
It looks like this now:
[image]

Comment: `self.eq1` is not defined. you have `self.q1_lbl` and `self.eq1_ent`

Comment: When you call `Entry.get()` it'll get the contents of that exact moment. Since you are calling `.get()` right after creating empty entry, it'll get you empty string only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.eq1` is not defined. you have `self.q1_lbl` and `self.eq1_ent`.
To access the label use `self.q1_lbl`.

To be able to set text to your label create them as following:

```
self.var = StringVar()
self.unit_name_lbl = Label(self, textvariable=self.var)
```

For example, from `redraw()` you can set `'text'` to `self.unit_name_lbl` like this : `self.var.set('text')`.

- Check if you missed `self` in `d.add_task(n, a, unit)`
- When you do `command=mod.add_to_queue(self.ea1_ent.get())` the `mod.add_to_queue` function will be called directly, if you want  to pass argument  to this function when user press the button, you can use `lambda`:

  ```
  command=lambda: mod.add_to_queue(self.ea1_ent.get)
  ```

Comment: Thank you fore the answer, someone else answered that as a comment, but deleted it, so I have corrected that. I still don't know how to change the labels amount1, amount 2 and all the q1-q3 and a1-a3 to what i write in the entry.